# SQL: Multi-Grouping and Sorting into 'bins'

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to capture any time an item occurs with other listed items so that I can do further work. So if item 1 occurs with item 2 and 3 in instance 1, with item 2 and 4 in instance 2, with items 3 and item 7 in instance 3, then my query should result in a listing of item 1, item 2, item 3, item 4, and item 7.

I believe this is in MS SQL, as I'm writing this in Access.

I have tried this in Excel first by running a pivot table on the #, the document # (these are the 2 I'm trying to sort out), date, and quantity by mixing up the rows and columns, to no avail.

```
SELECT TK, DocumentNo Count(*)
FROM access3
GROUP BY Tk, DocumentNo;
```

This results in

```
TK  DocumentNo  Expr1002
12364   SSPT267489  1
15826       1
16898   SSPT250724  1
17888   SSPT259200  1
17888   SSPT266740  1
17888   SSPT267709  1
17888   SSPT276036  1
18796   SSPT266145  1
18839   SSPT253433  1
18839   SSPT254744  1
19169   SSPT251179  1
19429   SSPT269249  1
19492   SSPT253796  1
19492   SSPT253797  1
```

But what I would want it to say is something like

```
(17888
12364
5781
90592) 
(First grouping, parentheses to indicate that 1788 has occurred with all of these numbers AT SOME POINT in a Document No.)

(1293812
1238
1293801
12381)

(1230918
21391
312039)

etc
```

Raw data example

```
SSPT245612  TK29078
SSPT245612  TK29195
SSPT245612  TK29199
SSPT245613  TK16330
SSPT245613  TK16331
SSPT245614  TK16330
SSPT245614  TK16331
SSPT245614  TK16373
SSPT245614  TK16737
SSPT245614  TK18008
SSPT245615  TK16916
SSPT245615  TK16917
SSPT245615  TK16918
SSPT245617  TK18329
SSPT245618  TK11309
SSPT245618  TK11320
SSPT245618  TK20245
SSPT245618  TK20454
SSPT245618  TK29725
SSPT245637  TK12137
SSPT245637  TK18815
SSPT245637  TK19088
SSPT245637  TK19090
SSPT245637  TK19232
SSPT245637  TK23330
SSPT245637  TK23331
SSPT245637  TK23947
SSPT245637  TK23948
SSPT245637  TK24006
SSPT245637  TK25505
SSPT245637  TK25506
SSPT245637  TK25507
SSPT245637  TK25508
SSPT245642  TK28365
SSPT245642  TK28366
SSPT245642  TK28372
SSPT245642  TK28373
SSPT245643  TK15293
SSPT245644  TK16330
SSPT245644  TK16331
SSPT245645  TK16330
SSPT245645  TK16331
SSPT245650  TK24811
SSPT245650  TK25744
SSPT245653  TK16330
SSPT245653  TK16331
SSPT245659  TK18333
SSPT245659  TK27345
SSPT245659  TK27346
SSPT245659  TK27347
SSPT245659  TK27385
SSPT245660  TK11300
SSPT245660  TK20066
SSPT245661  TK19179
SSPT245662  TK13738
SSPT245662  TK27514
SSPT245662  TK31244
SSPT245663  TK15484
SSPT245663  TK20167
SSPT245664  TK13981
SSPT245665  TK15293
SSPT245666  TK16330
SSPT245666  TK16331
SSPT245667  TK19688
SSPT245668  TK13331
SSPT245669  TK16330
```

Comment: Edit question to show sample raw data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access only supports a very limited subset of SQL and in some cases has its own unique syntax. This can be pretty limiting but in your case it should be sufficient. The trick here is to join the table to itself. The code below may not be perfect but it should point you in the right direction. It won't give the exact format of output you describe as SQl doesn't really lend itself to that format (although you could do it if you really wanted).

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.TK, b.TK
FROM access3 a JOIN access3 b ON a.DocumentNo = b.DocumentNo
WHERE NOT a.TK=b.TK
ORDER BY a.TK,b.TK
```

This will give you a table with two columns, the first will list all the TKs in order (multiple times each) the second will contain all the TKs that they have appeared with. Easier to just try it than to describe.

Comment: This looks like exactly what it is that I needed after cross-checking my original table. Thank you so much! Do you have any recommendation to learn more? I just ordered SQL Queries for Mere Mortals, have done the codecademy module, and I have Data Camp on my phone.

Comment: A follow up question would be: what program / IDE should I be using for querying instead of the Access console?

Comment: I don't have any books to recommend as I've never really used any. I mostly used sites like this to learn. As far as IDEs go, I will recommend some but the SQL dialect is determined by the database you are connecting to not the IDE, so using Access will always limit you. If you're serious about learning SQL then move away form Access. The good news is all the big SQL databases are free for development/learning (PostgreSQL, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Oracle Database). Pick one or several, install them and play.

Comment: As for IDEs they each come with their own but for cross platform work JetBrains Datagrip is the gold standard IMO. I use DBeaver because it's free.